# ASP.NET Base64 image source not displaying properly.

Tags: html, asp.net, image, base64

I am getting a Base64 string from Azure active directory via a Lambda function. This represents a users profile picture. I am then trying to display this in an ASP.NET page. It isn't working.

Here is the ASP.NET (The referenced HTML object is an ASP literal)

```
            using (var client = new AmazonLambdaClient(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast2))
            {
                var request = new InvokeRequest
                {
                    FunctionName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["lambdaArnPrefix"] + "lambda-wlyw-GetAzureAdUserThumbnail",
                    Payload = "\"" + Context.User.Identity.Name.ToString() + "\"",
                    InvocationType = InvocationType.RequestResponse

                };
                var response = client.Invoke(request);

                string result;
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.Payload))
                {
                    result = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }

                dynamic userThumbnail = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
                photo.Text = "<img src='data:image/jpg;base64," + userThumbnail.base64Image + "' width='100' height='100'/>";
```

The page however shows the broken image icon. if I view source, it seems OK to me? The base64 string does decode to an image if I use an online converter:

```
  <div class="panel-group">
                                            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                                                <div class="panel-heading">James Matson - Excellence<i class="fa fa-certificate pull-right"></i></div>
                                                <img src='data:image/jpg;base64,eyJvZGF0YS5lcnJvciI6eyJjb2RlIjoiUmVxdWVzdF9SZXNvdXJjZU5vdEZvdW5kIiwibWVzc2FnZSI6eyJsYW5nIjoiZW4iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IlJlc291cmNlICd0aHVtYm5haWxQaG90bycgZG9lcyBub3QgZXhpc3Qgb3Igb25lIG9mIGl0cyBxdWVyaWVkIHJlZmVyZW5jZS1wcm9wZXJ0eSBvYmplY3RzIGFyZSBub3QgcHJlc2VudC4ifX19' width='100' height='100'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem - apologies all. It turns out that my cached credentials were not there, which meant the returned Base64 string from the Lambda function was not in fact an image, but an error code from Azure AD, namely:

```
{"odata.error":{"code":"Request_ResourceNotFound","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Resource 'thumbnailPhoto' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present."}}}
```

Once I signed in properly, the image worked - so if anyone wants a working example of how this is achieved, please use the above :)